# after migration, newly uploaded images won't show up

Tags: images, uploads

I created a subdomain e.g dev.example.com where I uploaded a bunch of images and I did most of my dev.

I moved the WordPress install following the Codex instructions [Moving WordPress > Moving directories on your existing server](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Surprisingly, all my images were still there (no broken links)

Now, when I upload new images from the media uploader, I see the blue question mark square indicating that they're not here. I connect via FTP and see that files are not created.

EDIT: wp-content and uploads permissions are set to 755.

What can I do?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the upload folder still was defined as /dev. I changed that using the [upload url path enabled plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-url-path-enabler/).

Comment: yes, the main problem is a difference on the URl path. On each migration you can use a plugin  or change the url  from wp options table directly on phpMyadmin.